# How can I use overrides to completely change the layout of the Base Web calendar?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, baseweb

I am using [Uber's Base Web](https://baseweb.design) framework to create a web app and I would like to use the calendar/datepicker with range in a different layout. This framework is a huge learning curve for me but that's partly why I am using it and I need some help understanding how I can use the overrides to repurpose the calendar component in the following way:

**You can view the [sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/vibrant-glade-5opu4p).**

[Skyscanner](https://www.skyscanner.net) has the calendar layout I am trying to achieve, which is:

- Calendar is **not in a popup** but instead is underneath the date input fields.
- Instead of next/previous buttons, the calendar **scrolls vertically**.
- `locale="en-GB"` doesn't put Monday as the start of the week and throws a `RangeError: locale must contain localize property` error.

My understanding is that I can use the [overrides](https://baseweb.design/guides/understanding-overrides/) feature to create this by replacing the subcomponents, but I don't know **where to find the names of the subcomponents** and the customisable component properties.

I would really appreciate any guidance on how to do this. I have asked questions in the Slack for Base Web, but it is very inactive.

If I can figure out how to do this I will be able to customise all the other components/subcomponents.

Screenshot of Skyscanner's calendar:

[image]